# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please help me with the following problem I have.

I have a piece of JS code. When I put it in my list.html.erb file it works fine.
But when I put the code in test.js file and put it in my assets/javascripts folder, 
I do not know to attach it to application.js what to do with

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require "jquery_functions"
//= require_tree .
```

to make it work.

I have tried like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require "jquery_functions"
//= require_self
//= require 'test'
//= require_tree .
```

which did not work

The following is my test.js

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var txt="";
txt+="Width of div: " + $("#div2").width() + "</br>";
txt+="Height of div: " + $("#div1").height()+ "</br>";
txt+="va salm";
$("#div1").html(txt);
$("#div2").html(txt);
$("p").hide();
$(".test").hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
app/assets/javascripts/test.js
```

You can reference it in application.js as:

```
//= require test
```

However, by using:

```
//= require tree .
```

the file should be included anyway.

As a starting point, have you viewed source in your browser and checked that something like this appears in the html?

```
<script src="/assets/test.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```